# Override the behavior of base class private member in a derived class, C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, private

Suppose I have a class coming from the software package, so I do not have a way to change the design, that has the following form:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(int degree) 
  {
    ...
    initialize_points();
    ...
  }
  ...
private:
  ...
  void initialize_points() 
  { 
    int number = 1;
    // proceed to do computations using the number specified above
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

What I need is to have a class `B` being similar to class `A` in everything but the `number` specified in the function `initialize_points()`. Say, I want it to be 34 instead of 1.

Due to lack of experience I don't quite understand how I can derive such a class `B` (and should I do so, maybe it is better to write this as a new class mimicking the implementation of `A`?) from the class `A` since the function, whose behavior I want to override is the `private` member of the base class.

Thank you

Comment: You cannot do this without modifying A.

Comment: You could make this number be a template parameter for the class (or the function) perhaps

Comment: C++ provides something called "encapsulation", which means the designer/coder of `A` gets to decide the possible customisations by client code, and as presented `number` is not one of them.  With encapsulation, the maintainer of `A` can reason about possible client code dependencies: they know they can rename, remove or change `number` without breaking any client code.  If there were some way for client code to depend on these implementation details, library maintainers would have to inspect all client usage to do an impact study and client code rewrite before every change.

Comment: If you cannot modify this class, then you'll have to either provide your own substitute, or file a ticket with the vendor to modify the class for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that this cannot be done in C++. The primary mechanism by which a derived class could override what its base class does is virtual functions. Unless the base class defines virtual functions, there's nothing that can be done in the derived class to override it.